# Roblox Leaderstats not updating/only updating once

Tags: roblox

Roblox Leaderstats aren't updating correctly.
When told to update leaderstats, it sometimes doesn't update, and other times, it only updates once.
Code is below:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.sleep.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    local en = plr.leaderstats.Energy
    en.Value += 1
    print(en.value)
    wait()
    local speed = 5.07 * ((en.Value / 10) + 1)
    plr.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid").WalkSpeed = speed
    print(speed)
end)
```

On times it doesn't update, the `print(en.value)` says 1 while the leaderstat stays as 0.
When leaderstat only updates once, the print only updates once as well.
Edit: The leaderstat was defined/created in a previous script.

Comment: What code calls `game.ReplicatedStorage.sleep:FireServer()`? That may help decider why the updates are so flaky.

Comment: ```local plr = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local character = workspace:WaitForChild(plr.Name)
local tool = script.Parent
local animation = tool:WaitForChild("anim")
local animationTrack = character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)


tool.Activated:Connect(function()
 animationTrack:Play()
 wait(animationTrack.Length)
 game.ReplicatedStorage.sleep:FireServer()
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot to answer this, but I am using +=, you would assume it would add to the current amount as the hint says, but it doesn't
Old Code: `en.Value += 1`
What I do now: `en.Value = en.Value + 1`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32984944)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring the "en" variable right before you add one to the value in this function. This means that every time you run this code, you will reset the "en" variable. If you declare the variable outside of the scope of this function, it should get rid of your issues.

Comment: They are referencing a NumberValue object. The value persists between function calls.

Comment: No, because I had declared the leaderstat before in a seperate script. En was used as an attempt to fix the updating only once before. Sorry if it had confused you, I'll clarify it in the post.